# React state vs. Redux state (real usecase)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have read multiple tutorials how to make CRUD in React with Redux bot **none** of the authors explained **why** they are using Redux. (Like they are only using it for fancyness or because all other are using it.)

Citate from [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367):

> People often choose Redux before they need it.

Through further researching i learned that Redux is good for:

- Share state between components
- Let some data be accessable in the entire application

It does not exist a **wrong** or **right**. But only the **do what makes sense**.

#### My usecase

I have a component that uses a shared component:

```
¦-- domains/FooManagement/Components/Editor.jsx <-- Most-parent of the editor
¦-- domains/FooManagement/Components/..the children of Editor.jsx
¦-- shared/Components/Tabs/Tabs.jsx <-- Most-parent of the tabs
¦-- shared/Components/Tabs/..the children of Tabs.jsx
```

`Tabs.jsx` is used in `Editor.jsx`.

#### Which is the right approach?

**Approach 1: React state (I think its the right one)**

- Every dynamic rendering that can happen is stored in the state of `Editor.jsx`.
- onClick on a tab (nested shared component) calls a callback written in `Editor.jsx` that updates the state in `Editor.jsx`. This state change then rerenders the new active tab
- That means that on every other component like `Editor.jsx` that uses the same nested `Tabs.jsx`, the changes for the tabs must be handled in the editor.

Code example:

```
/**
 * domains/FooManagement/Components/Editor.jsx
 * or 
 * domains/BarManagement/Components/Editor.jsx
 */
onTabChange(activeTab) {
    this.state.activeTab = activeTab;
    this.setState(this.state);
}
```

I think this is the right approach because:

- I dont need the state of the editor or the tabs component in the entire application. But only on this view one time. Like the [short term duration definition](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/).

**Approach 2: Redux state**

- `Editor.jsx` has its own state
- `Tabs.jsx` has its own state
- States are stored in Redux
- `Editor.jsx` dont passes data down to `Tabs.jsx` because `Tabs.jsx` takes the data from the Redux store

Benefit:

- The code example above must not be in `Editor.jsx` because its not the editor's interests how the tabs component behaves. (Or should the editor interests?)

I think this is bad because

- Its too much magic in here. Immagine there comes more components in the editor like sortables, tables, etc. In the `Editor.jsx` you will not see what can render your view. It is hidden in the other components.

But if its all handled in `Editor.jsx`, you have the overview and the control of all what must be rendered on any change.

**What is the right approach for you?**

Comment: There are 3 components: Sales.js, Totals.js and Payment.js and each state is stored inside its own component: how do you access how many products are being selected for a sale in a Sales.js to display total amount inside Totals.js and also in Payment.js to process payments?

Comment: You can solve this still with Approach 1. When all the state is stored in your most-parent component you can access it from there. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

speaking of real usecases, I'm working on an everyday growing project, at first, pure React state management seemed like a very convenient way to develop, and it was working just fine when the components structures were still somehow flattened, but as we go along it, the project gets more complicated and by complicated I mean, more component become nested, and one parent has a serie of nested children, so we have to pass props all the way from the parent to the most furthest child, and whenever we need to rerender the parent, all the children have to go through this cycle also, as for your case, if you know that your project won't get way more complicated, and `Tabs.jsx` won't have maybe something like `form` that contains further nested `subForm` that contains a `Grid` maybe, you surely don't need to complicate your life with Redux, but as I stated earlier, for us we started to notice that at this stage, integrating Redux would be considerable

Comment: Summarized you suggest to use redux if a component tree gets greater than ca. 5 nested components?

Comment: more like whenever you have a big project with many components, and your component state needs to be shared globally across different components, sometimes you have 5 nested components but with no need to mutate the state in a complex way, therefore React state in this case still seems appropriate.